# PayPal API specifying currency SGD

Tags: reactjs, django, paypal, payment

I'm developing a payment system with PayPal API. Everything works except that the transaction is in USD and not SGD (like how I want it to be).

PayPal Button from react-paypal-button-v2

```
<PayPalButton
  currency='SGD'
  amount={parcel.basePrice}
  onSuccess={successPaymentHandler}
/>
```

Script to add PayPal button

```
 const addPayPalScript = () => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src =
      "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=CLIENT_ID&currency=SGD";
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => {
      setSdkReady(true);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  };
```

I followed the documentation here. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/customize-sdk/

Comment: Use currency as following snipts
 <PayPalButton
                amount={100}
                options={{            
                    currency:"SGD"
                }}
            
            />

Answer (score 0):

SGD ***is*** a [PayPal supported currency](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/currency-codes/), and your code's usage appears correct according to the documentation for that unofficial react-paypal-button-v2 component, so I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

Try the newer official [@paypal/react-paypal-js](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js) instead.

Comment: I specified ```locale: en_SG``` in the intialState and it worked. Wonder if that is a good solution?

Comment: I don't see why it should make a difference

Answer (score 0):

You can use the currency inside options rather than as a props in component code will be like

```
  <PayPalButton
                amount={100}
                options={{            
                    currency:"SGD"
                }}
            
            />
```